# How to disable multiple items in dropdown when selected an item in other dropdown?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblstarttime" runat="server" Text="StartTime :" Style="font-size: 80%; font-weight: bold">
            </asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlStartTime" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" Style="font-size: small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlStartTime_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>

        <td style="width: 10%"></td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEndTime" runat="server" Text="EndTime :" Style="font-size: 70%; font-weight: bold">
            </asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlEndTime" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" Style="font-size: small">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnsub" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnsub_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

protected void DdlStartTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem selectedItem = DdlStartTime.SelectedItem;

    foreach (ListItem item in DdlEndTime.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == selectedItem.Value)
        {
            DdlEndTime.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When I selected a `StartTime` in my `DdlStartTime` then `endTime` items should greater than the second drop down list.

Here I can't get the exact thing that I want.. can anyone help me out?

Comment: what are values in dropdown?

Comment: 24 hrs as 15 min slots